# Commonalities and differences between Apache/Tomcat and IIS7 from architecture viewpoint

Tags: c#, java, apache, tomcat, iis-7

IIS7 has httpmodules and httphandlers, I guess Apache/Tomcat have something similar. What are they ? What events would be missing on one side or another ?

Answer (score 1):

The architectures are nothing alike, and as far as I know there is no reasonable way to compare them directly.

Tomcat implements the Java Servlet and JSP standards, while IIS follows no standard but it's own.

So, with IIS, you wind up writing code that interacts directly with the server architecture (httpmodules and httphandlers), while with Tomcat, one typically does not write code that interacts directly with the server. In Java, web applications are written to work with the standard api and lifecycle, and Tomcat is merely one implementation of that standard.